# Server error on Amadeus Hotel Search API

Tags: api, amadeus

I'm trying to hit the Self-Service Hotel Search API through the Amadeus API Explorer.

It seems to work only for certain cities. For example, it works for the following request - city: `PAR`
`https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=PAR&radius=50&radiusUnit=KM&includeClosed=false&bestRateOnly=true&view=NONE&sort=NONE`

However, if I change the cityCode to `NYC` or `SFO`, it gives a **500** interval server error

`https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=NYC&radius=50&radiusUnit=KM&includeClosed=false&bestRateOnly=true&view=NONE&sort=NONE`

The error response -

```
{ code: 38189,
   title: 'Internal error',
   detail: 'An internal error occured, please contact your administrator',
   status: 500 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting this issue, it was caused by a backend migration on our side.
We checked your query and it works now so everything should be fixed.

Keep in mind that our sandbox environment only offers a limited set of data to allow you to try the APIs and prototype with them.
We will be launching the production environment (and the tools to request migration to production) in Q4 2018.